# What are the initial/zero values for different data types in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Zero values, as in what would *placehold* the value when a key in a mapping is not yet assigned.

Comment: how may i set an entire mapping to its initial state again which is empty?

Comment: @SArv See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045986/8515472

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Solidity docs they are called *[initial values](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#delete)*:

- **Value Types**
- `boolean`: `false`
- `string`: `""`
- `int`: `0`
- `uint`: `0`
- `fixed`: `0.0` (presumably; this type is not fully supported)
- `enum`: *the first element of the enum*
- `address`: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (or `address(0)`)
- `function`

  - `internal`: empty function, returning initial values (if return is needed)
  - `external`: function that throws when called
- **Reference Types**
- `mapping`: *empty mapping*
- `struct`: *a struct where all members are set to initial values*
- `array`

  - dynamically-sized: `[]`
  - fixed-sized: *an array of the fixed size where all elements are set to initial values*

When you use the `delete` keyword it will assign the *initial value* to the variable, except for mappings, where it doesn't have any effect. For structs the `delete` keyword will recurse into the members, unless they are mappings.

Comment: How do I check if in `mapping(uint8 -> address) testMap` the address is still initial value? Is this correct: `testMap[0] == address(0)`?

Comment: @Jagrut Use ```testMap[0] == 0x0 ```